# Equivalent "chop" function in Maple

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maple

The [Chop](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) feature in Mathematica replaces approximate real numbers in expression that are close to zero by the exact integer. I am searching for an equivalent function in Maple. Kindly note that I am NOT in search of trunc, round, frac etc. as they round off other floats to integers. I am only interested in "chopping" or rounding the near to 0 numbers to 0.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Check out Maple's command [fnormal](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=fnormal).

Comment: I wish to "chop" an array such as [10^(-10)*x^2, 10^(-8)]. This should return [0 , 0] but instead it returns [(1/10000000000)*x^2, 0.00000000] on using fnormal. I tried changing precision, digits etc but none work. However the above expression works if we enter the floats directly such as 0.000025 etc.

Comment: what if `x=10^5` ?  Mathematicas `Chop` will not chop that either w/o a value for x.

Comment: You are correct that **fnormal** will only work on floats. You can use **evalf** before **fnormal** to convert exact rationals in an expression to floats. **fnormal** does not care about the **x** in the expression; it only looks at the floats. If you intend for your numbers to be floats, then you can enter **10^(-10)** as **1e-10** or **10.^(-10)**.